# rails app on nginx+passenger not showing custom error pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails app running on nginx 1.2.0 and passenger 3.0.7. I would like to have the custom error pages in the rails app (e.g. /rail_app/public/500.html) be displayed when the appropriate http error occurs within the app.

Here is my current nginx config file:

```
http {
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.7;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #access_log  /opt/nginx/logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /var/www/dashboard/current/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_min_instances 1;
#       listen 443;
#       ssl on;
#       ssl_certificate /opt/nginx/conf/server.crt;
#       ssl_certificate_key /opt/nginx/conf/server.key;
        error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
        location = /500.html {
            root /var/www/dashboard/current/public/;
        }
    }
}
```

This configuration does not show the rails app customer error page rather just sends the http error status code to the client.

Anyone know what it takes to have nginx/passenger send the rails app custom error page to the client with the http error status code?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
# We use the x just because it is for all 5xx errors.
error_page 500 502 503 504 /5xx.html;
location = /5xx.html {
    alias /var/www/dashboard/current/public/;
}
```

Reconfiguring the `root` directive makes no sense, as it is already set to the path you specified before. The `alias` ensures that the specific location is internally matched to a different location on the file system. All incoming request parameters should be passed along and if your Rails app is taking care of things at this point it should answer. Just make sure that your Rails app isn't answering with a 500 status again (I don’t know what would happen then).

**Related Links**

- [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing `passenger_intercept_errors on;` in your nginx config

see the [passenger docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#passenger_intercept_errors) for this directive for more info

Answer (score 0):

The config I use:

```
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

location = /50x.html {
   root   html;
}
```

Comment: Benjamin, thanks for the reply. I tried that and it did not work. Here is a little more detail about what i am trying to accomplish: when database is down...i want the rails app to display the custom 500 error page instead of just sending http 500 through to the client. Maybe i should catch the activerecord exception? just not sure how.

Comment: Error in prod log: `/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Fri Jun 14 10:29:18 -0400 2013
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  Can't connect to MySQL server on '169.254.1.51' (113)
    /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.17/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `real_connect'`